# Prevent Sitecore from creating the sitename#lang cookie in jss/nextjs app

Tags: jss, nextjs, layout-service, cookies

Is there a way to block Sitecore from creating the `{website}#lang` cookie? When Sitecore's Layout Service is used with a headless app (a **next js** app)?

Will it be enough to add a `processor` in `getLayoutServiceContext`, that inherits `JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor`, that will remove the lang cookie? So that Layout Service will not send over the lang cookie to the next js app, that will sequentially set it up to the visitor's browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can create a custom processor to remove the lang cookie for Layout Service requests:

Create a new class that inherits from JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor.
Override the Process method and remove the lang cookie from the response object.
Register your custom processor in the httpRequestBegin pipeline after the JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor processor.
Here is an example of what the code for the custom processor might look like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Configuration;
using Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Core;
using Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.LayoutService.Pipelines.GetLayoutServiceContext;

namespace MyCustom.Processors
{
    public class RemoveLangCookieProcessor : JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(GetLayoutServiceContextArgs args)
        {
            base.Process(args);

            var httpContext = args.Context.RequestServices.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
            httpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("{website}#lang");
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to register your custom processor in the httpRequestBegin pipeline after the JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor processor:

```
<httpRequestBegin>
    <processor type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.LayoutService.Pipelines.Services.GetLayoutServiceContext.JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine"/>
    <processor type="MyCustom.Processors.RemoveLangCookieProcessor, MyCustom"/>
</httpRequestBegin>
```